# Structuring MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following url structure, and just trying to figure out the best Routes to configure.

**EDIT: Added more url's**

/cars/{name} (shows general information about a car)

/cars/{name}/models (shows a list of models for a particular car)

/cars/{name}/models/{id} (shows a specific model for a particular car)

/cars/{name}/models/edit (add a new model which would be an action)

/cars/{name}/models/{id}/owners (a list of owners for a particular model)

/cars/{name}/models/{id}/owners/create (add a new owner)

So far, I have

```
         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CarReleases",
            url: "cars/{name}/models/{id}",
            defaults:
                new
                    {
                        controller = "Releases",
                        action = "Index",
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional
                    }
            );
```

This works if I use /cars/{name}/models, but obviously, I don't have the action available for the models page. Do I have to create a new route map for this situation?

I also have the CarController, which is mapped as follows:

```
          routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Cars",
            url: "cars/{name}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

As you can see, I have a general mixture of actions and dynamic requests. Bit confused the best way to put this into maproutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order your routes **from the most specific to the least specific**. In my example all actions are mapped to the controller `Cars`; however, you may separate them. For example:

Owners:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "owners",
            url: "cars/{name}/models/{id}/owners/{action}/{ownerId} ",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "OwnerIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional, ownerId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Models:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "models",
            url: "cars/{name}/models/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "ModelIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Cars:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Cars",
            url: "/cars/{name}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Notice the default action was changed to Index so it lists all when you omit the action and Id (you may need to change it if you decide to keep them all in one controller)

Regarding your question whether you should keep them in one single controller, I think that's fine unless you would like to separate admin functions (edit, delete, etc) from viewing. In any case you can still have them in one controller and just add the `Authorize` attribute.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ViewResult Delete(int id){}
```

Comment: Tried this out, but I don't think it quite fits. I've modified the question a bit to maybe help explain things a bit further. It is a bit more complex than I thought.

Comment: When you place the {action} in the route, does that mean that it is required in the requesting url? e.g. /cars/camaro/models/list/2013, /cars/camaro/models (will work), /cars/camaro/edit.

Comment: It is not required since you specify a Default value, in my example it is Index. But you can change it of course to `List` so /cars/camaro/models will work and will be routed the List action in your controller.

Comment: I understand that aspect, but with the following scenario:
/cars/camaro/models,
/cars/camaro/models/2013
The first is mapped to the default List action, the second does then not have an action in the url. How does that request get mapped without having /cars/camaro/models/model/2013 or the like? I would rather have it clean. Would I have to add a RedirectToAction within the main List action if the id exists?

Comment: You could have your Index action with an id parameter. Then, check whether the id is provided and depending on this show a list or a single element. By the default the MVC template provides a `Details` action. So you do  `/cars/camaro/models/details/2013`

Comment: Hmmm. I have my maproute as "cars/{name}/models/{action}/{id}". If I do the following: "cars/camaro/models" I get the default index action firing. If I do "cars/camaro/models/2013", I am getting 404, it's not routing through anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22866/discussion-between-mickyjtwin-and-ulises)